# Creating a TextField with autocomplete

Tags: ember.js

I have to create a **TextField** with *autocomplete* in Ember to fetch data from Database on each key press based on match.

Is their any built-in widget in Ember for this ?

Comment: Here is an [embercast](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/building-an-autocomplete-widget-part-1) if anyone looking for an solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in component in Ember.js, but from experience such component would be very easy to write yourself. On EmberCamp Trek Glowacki said he hopes no widget library will be ever needed.

You could also use Typeahead from Twitter Bootstrap or AutoComplete from jQuery UI which can be made to work together.

Comment: [Bootstrap Typeahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637966/emberjs-data-source-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead)

Answer (score 8):

You can use events of Ember.Textfield to do this. (Coffeescript and Jade)

Search View

```
App.SearchView = Ember.View.extend

    templateName: 'search'

    searchTerm: null

    searchTextField: Ember.TextField.extend

      insertNewline: ->
        # if the user hits the enter key, you can do something different or call the same function
        @get('controller').search(@get('searchTerm'))

      keyUp: (e) ->
        # validate the item on every keypress
        if (e.currentTarget.value.length > 0)
          @get('controller').search(@get('searchTerm'))
```

Search Template

```
script(type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='search')

{{view view.searchTextField valueBinding="view.searchTerm" placeholder="search"}}

<button {{action "search"}}>search</button>
```

Search Controller

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  search: (searchTerm) ->
    # do your search
```

** added missing parenthesis

Comment: Would there be a good way to add a 300ms delay on the search? I am filtering a semi-large DOM list and I don't want Ember trying to filter for ever character entered. If the customer is trying to type in a name. Figured a min delay between filtering might help this.

Comment: Yes, I can add it to the code shortly.  But, basically, you would set a timer in javascript that would run the search function, and if another keypress came in, you could cancel that timer, and then set another.  That way, fast typing won't cause a search everytime, but a break of x in typing would.

Comment: @ootoovak wrap the body of `keyUp` in a call to `Ember.run.debounce` or Lodash's `_.debounce`.

Answer (score 3):

EmberCasts has a good video on [how to build an auto complete widget](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/building-an-autocomplete-widget-part-1).

[I asked them about the millisecond delay](https://twitter.com/ootoovak/status/337164600095166464) on filtering and I was told they will cover that in the next episode they do on it.

Comment: It's too bad EmberCasts doesn't seem to add new videos, the one you refer to is quick and very easy to implement, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The github project ember-typeahead](https://github.com/charlieridley/ember-typeahead) has made a good start in this regard as well.